# Access HTTPS from different port

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, ssl, https

While web browsing, how do you redirect HTTPS URLs to a port other than the standard 443?

Due to Windows XP's inability to handle name-based hosting with SSL, I'm forced to remap port 443 to a unique port via a load balancer for each SSL-enabled Apache website I host. However, this makes it impossible to test the sites without the load balancer, since all web browsers seem to hardcode HTTPS URLs to port 443. Is there any way to change this, such as via a Firefox extension? I've searched, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply specify the port when browsing:

```
https://hostname:port/path
```

Ex.

```
https://gmail.com:443/
```

Also, do you perhaps mean that *Internet Explorer* does not support [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) on XP? Chrome, Firefox, and Apache all support SNI (name-based virtual hosts over SSL) fully on Windows XP and newer.